# Point domain to cPanel and Google Apps

Tags: email, g-suite, mx-record

I want to point my domain to cPanel for hosting and Google Apps for email and same time I want the domain to ignore mx entry on the server so if the server goes down I can still receiving emails to Google Apps

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want Google to handle your mail, and bypass your server all together, just edit your domain's DNS settings with Google's MX records, while pointing everything else to the cPanel server.

Here's what a BIND config file looks like on one of the domains I manage that does just this (slightly modified):

```
@               IN      MX      1       ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@               IN      MX      5       ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@               IN      MX      5       ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@               IN      MX      10      ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@               IN      MX      10      ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@               IN      A       {cPanel IP Address}
www             IN      A       {IP Address}
```

You can edit www with a wildcard such as...

```
 *.            IN      A       {IP Address}
```

Comment: OK, But this way if the server goes down I will not be able to receive E-Mails

Comment: That's why it is an absolute requirement to have two different name servers - so that if 1 name server goes down, your domain will still resolve. If you're using cPanel as your nameserver, then I recommend at least using your Domain Registrar as your secondary nameserver - most Domain Registrars provide some functionality, anyway.

Comment: My domain registered at Netfirms.. When I added Google Apps MX to the domain and then I shut down the server it hasn't resolved the MX

Comment: Check the domain's Name Server Setup / DNS Setup. There should be at least two NS entries. If all of them point to your server, then that's why. In addition to adding the MX records on your Registrar, you need to also point the domain to their name server.

Comment: I have no option to add more nameservers.. I can add two nameservers only which I point to my server with

Comment: Either change one of those to point to the domain registrar's name server, or stop using your own name server all together, and let them do the NS work completely.

Comment: Ok, If I pointed the two nameservers to Netfirms how can I point the domain to open the hosted site from my server?

Comment: Judging from this discussion, it sounds like you're either way in over your head, or need to ask another question on the main site in order to get all the help you need.

Comment: +1. This discussion is getting out of the scope of the original question, so I think you should either ask a new question, or contact your Domain Registrar's support to help get the DNS settings implemented properly through their site.